# How to change attributes

Tags: html, angular

I have a component which features a set of three custom buttons and I want to use these buttons as controls for a sound recorder.

I got stuck in the first phase, where I want to change the symbols displayed on the buttons, according to their function.

I tried to achieve that by changing their `xlink:href` attributes (I use svg), but got this in he console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./RecordComponent class RecordComponent - inline template:5:45 caused by: this.roundButtonOne.getAttribute is not a function
```

Any idea why and how I could implement this with an Angular approach? Here is the code:

```js
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-record',
  template: `
    <svg class='roundButtonOne icon'>
      <use #roundButtonOne xlink:href='#mic'(click)='onRecord()'/>
    </svg>
    <svg class='roundButtonTwo icon'>
      <use #roundButtonTwo xlink:href='#live' />
    </svg>
    <svg class='roundButtonThree icon'>
      <use #roundButtonThree xlink:href='#upload' />
    </svg>
    `
})
export class RecordComponent {

  private recording: boolean = false;

  @ViewChild('roundButtonOne') roundButtonOne: HTMLElement;
  @ViewChild('roundButtonTwo') roundButtonTwo: HTMLElement;
  @ViewChild('roundButtonThree') roundButtonThree: HTMLElement;

  onRecord() {
    this.recording = true;

    switch(this.roundButtonOne.getAttribute('xlink:href')) {
      case '#mic':
        this.record();
        break;
    }
  }

  record() {
    this.roundButtonOne.setAttribute('xlink:href','#mic-small');
    this.roundButtonTwo.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#pause');
    this.roundButtonThree.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#stop');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you call *console.log* on one of the button elements, you can see that it is an instance of *ElementRef*, not *HTMLElement*.

So...

Import ElementRef from @angular/core:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
```

Change the buttons type from HTMLElement to ElementRef:

```
@ViewChild('roundButtonOne') roundButtonOne: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('roundButtonTwo') roundButtonTwo: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('roundButtonThree') roundButtonThree: ElementRef;
```

Get *nativeElement* from *ElementRef* object and then call *setAttribute()* / *getAttribute()* methods:

```
this.roundButtonOne.nativeElement.getAttribute('xlink:href');

this.roundButtonOne.nativeElement.setAttribute('xlink:href','#mic-small');
```

Comment: how to put the element id in @ViewChild ('') when the element's id is dynamically generated in a loop ?

Answer (score 2):

You also can use direct property of `Element` like `src, href, text`.

TS

```
this.link.nativeElement.href = 'microsoft.com';
this.link.nativeElement.text = 'Microsoft';
this.myimage.nativeElement.src = 
   'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flowers-and-leaves/42/flower_2-512.png';
```

HTML

```
<img #myimage width="100px" 
             src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nature-20/512/79-512.png" />
<a #mylink href="google.com">Google</a>
<br>
<button (click)="change()">Change</button>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-set-attribute-element?file=src/app/app.component.html