# Turn checked state to false after closing a modal

Tags: jquery, html, angular, bootstrap-4

I am implementing a bootstrap switch inside a modal with Angular 8.

By default, it is in `off` state, but when I turn it `on` and close the modal it still in `on` state.

**HTML:**

```
<div align="center" class="custom-control custom-switch">
 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches">
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">Try it</label>
</div>
```

**TS code:**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    $('#modalDisplay').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#customSwitches').attr(':checked', false);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: using jQuery inside angular is bad practice... take help from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097796

Comment: I solved it by using ".prop" insted the actual ".attr"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using ".prop" insted the actual ".attr"

Even though their page shows that the "state" is an attribute, using property it modied the button.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    $('#modalDisplay').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#customSwitches').prop(':checked', false);
    }.bind(this));
}
```